# WiFi, 20.04 LTS, sometimes works, sometimes doesn't

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

Dell 5570 laptop, running 20.04 LTS.  Random issue with WiFi whereas sometimes it loads and works fine, sometimes not.

Can't figure it, but it is frustrating because a reboot doesn't guarantee it will work.  It is truly random so rebooting works with a degree of probability akin to rolling a 7 or 11 on a crap table.